# DAO method in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am unable to get the count of records by openining Ms Access Query, I use the following code.

```
Private Sub CmdGetData_Click()
Dim WRK As Workspace
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim StrSql As String

Set WRK = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
Set db = CurrentDb
StrSql = "select * from [QrySalePatti]"

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(StrSql, dbOpenDynaset)

Do While (Not rs.EOF)
  rs.MoveFirst
  rs.MoveLast
  MsgBox rs.RecordCount
Loop

exitRoutine:
If Not (db Is Nothing) Then
     db.Close
     Set db = Nothing
End If

Set WRK = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You have done well to add the code in question, but a vital detail is still missing: What is the *expected* output of your program and what is the *actual* output that you get? Please use the `edit` link below your question to add that piece of information.

Answer (score 1):

You should not need a `Do While` loop to get the `RecordCount`.

```vb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(StrSql, dbOpenDynaset)
With rs
    If Not (.BOF And .EOF) Then
        .MoveLast
    End If
    MsgBox .RecordCount
End With
```

However if your goal is only to count the rows from `QrySalePatti`, you could use a `SELECT Count(*)` query and read the value returned from that.

```vb
StrSql = "SELECT Count(*) AS row_count FROM [QrySalePatti]"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(StrSql)
MsgBox rs!row_count
```

Or you could use a `DCount` expression.

```vb
MsgBox DCount("*", "QrySalePatti")
```